# How to roop typescript's type for params?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I set `listData[index][field] = newValue as any`, it's working, but I don't want to use any.

I still try to use `newValue: string | number | Date` still shows the error

How do I let the typescript working for the setting `listData[index][field] = newValue` ?

```
interface Sons {
  name: string;
  address?: string;
  date?: Date;
  age?: number;
}

interface Parents extends Sons {
  height: string;
}

const parentList: Parents = {
  name: '',
  height: '',
}

const listData: Parents[] = [parentList]


class Test {
  update<K extends keyof Parents>(index: number, field: K, newValue: string ) {
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Parents[K]'.
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
    listData[index][field] = newValue
}
```

Comment: Apparently, it should be `newValue: Parents[K]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Parents[K]` instead of `string` for `newValue`. This is called an [Indexed Access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) which dynamically looks up the type of a given property key (`K`) on the `Parents` `interface`.

```
interface Sons {
  name: string;
  address?: string;
  date?: Date;
  age?: number;
}

interface Parents extends Sons {
  height: string;
}

const parentList: Parents = {
  name: '',
  height: '',
}

const listData: Parents[] = [parentList]


class Test {
  update<K extends keyof Parents>(index: number, field: K, newValue: Parents[K] ) {
    listData[index][field] = newValue;
  }
}

declare const test: Test;

test.update(0, "height", "very tall");
test.update(0, "date", new Date());
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsQGdkG8CwAUMsiHALYQBcyWYUoA5gNxElwAmHUEWWA-DToMQLNsg5xIg5ABEpEVsWRxGEGSACu5AEbQlAXyJFQkWIhQAFOD3A4IAD0ggOODNjziAFhGCMvYEL0TIbGhAiYdMgADjYQ4AAywHQ01rZgOAC8nspklDQA5AUANN6+-oHIRaWERoREEdhgyAA2yWDyYHCpcXYA2gC6yNl9selJdANhDS1wfMgAKrzNBMqa0ZKQADwA0siOzq7IANYQAJ7oMMhp8RkAfAAUoByONFq60MXIMMAQLRw0HZfEAQADuADU4C1NNRrr0Mn0dkMAJQ5EgkNp0TpwPrPRwDPo-P4cIbZEEQqEwpQkOp1IgvBCzHjIRpRSApRbLJREdlgAB0602EAeAAYvgAiHx+ALiiUAN2gZ2QXRaLXFyKUvIFGwUoolQtlpDBcl1yI1QA)

Comment: Thanks, I learn it a lot, thanks for your help.